# FieldDoesNotExist error on Django production server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

After pushing my Django app to my production server I have got this error :

```
FieldDoesNotExist at /

Class_B has no field named <function DO_NOTHING at 0x7f5993ed3440>
```

The error seems to come from a query to my databse (the same PostgreSQL database that I use for my development).

Here is a simplified version of my model.py :

```
class Class_B(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    field2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'class_B'
        select_on_save = True

class Class_A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.OneToOneField('An_other_class', db_index=True,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey('Class_A', models.DO_NOTHING,
                               db_column='field1', db_index=True,
                               related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'class_A'
```

The query on which the error appeared :

```
print(Class_A.objects.all())
```

There isn't any migration to do and some queries to the database work.

I'm using an httpd server on CentOS with wod_wsgi. My python version is 3.3 and Django 1.8.0.

Any known solution for this error?

Comment: Without `self` ? Why using a `class`, use a `function`.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and the code that generates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
field2 = models.ForeignKey('Class_A', models.DO_NOTHING,
                           db_column='field1', db_index=True,
                           related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
```

you're passing `models.DO_NOTHING` as positional argument instead of a named argument. This is legal in Django >= 1.9 (and will be required in Django >= 1.10), but for previous Django versions the second positional argument to `ForeignKey` is the `to_field` option, hence your error message.

To make a long story short, you want

```
 models.ForeignKey('Class_A', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, ...)
```